# Como receber id's no controller/model

Tags: codeigniter

Estou criando um projeto e esbarrei em um problema.
A ideia é o seguinte: adicionar participantes em um evento específico.
Já criei tudo certinho: controllers, models e views.
A minha dúvida é como que faço para o controller/model receber as id's de cada participante que selecionei em um `multi-select` da view `adicionar_participante`.

Tenho uma tabela (participantes_eventos) cujas colunas são: 
`id_relação`, `id_usuario`, `id_evento`.

Assim, para cada participante em um evento tenho uma relação nessa tabela.

Código da VIEW:

```html
<h1>Adicionar participantes</h1>

<form action="adicionar-participante-evento" method="post">
  <select multiple class="form-control" name="id_usuario">
 <?php foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) { ?>
   <option value="<?= $usuario['id_usuario']; ?>"><?= $usuario['nome_usuario']; ?></option>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Código do Controller Eventos:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EventoController extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->view('template/cabecalho');
  $this->load->view('template/footer');
 }

 public function index() {
  $eventos = $this->EventosModel->listarTodos();
  $dadosEventos = array('eventos' => $eventos ); 
  $this->load->view('eventos/index', $dadosEventos);
 }

 public function adicionarParticipante(){
  $usuarios = $this->UsuariosModel->listarTodos();
  $dadosUsuarios = array('usuarios' => $usuarios);
  $this->load->view('eventos/adicionar_participante', $dadosUsuarios);
 }

 public function adicionarParticipanteEvento(){
  $id_usuarios_participantes = array(
   '' => '';
  );

 }
}
```

Código do Model Eventos:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EventosModel extends CI_Model {

 public function listarTodos(){
  $eventos = $this->db->get('eventos')->result_array();
  return $eventos;
 }
}
```

Comment: Edite a pergunte e adicione os códigos do controlador e dos modelos do banco de dados. O CodeIgniter possui suporte nativo de relações entre modelos? Aliás, como é novo aqui, sugiro que faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do funcionamento do site. Sempre é útil.

Comment: imagino que esteja enviando esses dados por um form da sua view, e se for isso, esta conseguindo pegar esses dados no controller? não só coloque os codigos do seu controller e model, como da sua view tbm.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz ja adicionei os códigos. Eles são básicos, estou aprendendo agora PHP e CodeIgniter.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já adicionei.

Answer (score 0):

Então, para que possa ser enviado vários itens selecionados você deve colocar como um array assim:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="id_usuario[]">
```

Eu imagino que esteja trabalhando com rotas, não da pra saber, mas no seu controller em seu metodo que esta recebendo esses dados, imagino que seja o `adicionarParticipanteEvento` deve fazer com que receba assim:

```
public function adicionarParticipanteEvento(){

    $id_usuarios_participantes = $this->input->post('id_usuario');

    // somente para ver se esta vindo certo e depois trabalhar com esses dados
    var_dump($id_usuarios_participantes); 
}
```

E uma dica que dou e que não acho correto do que esta fazendo é chamar essas views no __construct (não tem nada a ver com o seu problema, mas só uma dica mesmo).

Comment: Marcelo, consegui receber as ids do modo que você escreveu.
Muito obrigado! Sem querer abusar, você poderia me dizer como faria para chamar as view(cabecalho e footer) sem ser pelo __construct.

Comment: E outra coisa, como faço, por exemplo, para receber os dados (cpf, email, nome) de cada um dos usuários cujas IDs eu recebi pela form.

Criei uma função no UsuariosModel
`public function dadosUsuario($id_usuario){
  $this->db->where('id_usuario', $id_usuario);
  $usuario = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result_array();
  return $usuario;
 }
}`

Como faria pro controller passar isoladamente cada uma das Ids para a função e como receber as informações isoladas de cada um dos usuários.

Comment: entao Gabriel, quando a chamada das views o pq acho errado deixar no __construct é que toda vez que qualquer metodo do controller for chamado irá sempre executar o construtor da classe, principios básicos ok. Vc pode colocar essas views nos metodos que precisam dela mesmo, ou até criar um template para isso.
E para passar o id do usuario para o model, uma maneira que pode fazer isso é por um loop (foreach)